# Mongoose Schema registration - passing config info

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

What's a good way to pass configuration information while registering mongoose schemas and using them?

Say in the below example, I want to make the read preference and timeout value come from a config file... `"read: ['nearest']}, safe: {wtimeout: 10000})"`

something like => `"read: [dbConfig.readPrefence]}, safe: {wtimeout: dbConfig.writeTimoutMS})", what's a good way to pass dbConfig?`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var blogSchema = new Schema({
  title:  String,
  author: String,
  body:   String,
  comments: [{ body: String, date: Date }],
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  hidden: Boolean,
  meta: {
    votes: Number,
    favs:  Number
  }
}, {read: ['nearest']}, safe: {wtimeout: 10000}));
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution may depend on how you've organized your files, meaning what you might be asking is how to pass around a configuration to multiple files which each contain a schema.  But first looking at the simple case, a single schema exists within this file, I would recommend loading the configuration from there and pass in the values.

**config.json**

```
{
    "read": "nearest",
    "safe": true
}
```

**my-schema.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    config = require('./config.json');

var blogSchema = new Schema({
    title:  String,
    author: String,
    body:   String,
    comments: [{ body: String, date: Date }],
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    hidden: Boolean,
    meta: {
        votes: Number,
        favs:  Number
    }
}, {
    read: config.read,
    safe: config.safe
});
```

If you have multiple schemas and you'd rather load the configuration only once and pass that around, then I'd recommend sending it within the require call of the schema file.  For example:

**app.js**

```
var mySchema = require("./my-schema.js")(config);
```

**my-schema.js**

```
module.exports = function(config) { ... }
```